# Реверс-инжиниринг протокола обмена по радиоканалу

Tags: reverse-engineering, передача-данных, протоколы

Есть счетчик горячей воды с контролем температуры типа Профит РМД: http://www.sayany.ru/produktsiya/schetchiki-vody/94-schetchik-vody-profit-rmd-s-kontrolem-temperatury-gvs

Счетчик оснащен радиоинтерфейсом 433 МГц. Но так как счетчик питается от батарейки, он (наверное) начинает передавать что-либо только при получении запроса.

В инструкции и крайне скудной информации в интернете кроме названия протокола: РМД, мне найти ничего не удалось. Проскакивала еще информация, что другие приборы этого производителя работают по протоколу HD. Один и тот же это протокол или разные сказать затрудняюсь. Никаких ссылок и упоминаний о связи этих протоколов с общеизвестными стандартными протоколами обмена мне найти не удалось. На некоторых сайтах находил информацию, что фирма на запросы о протоколе упорно не отвечает.

Поэтому и возник интерес к расшифровке этого протокола, например для целей автоматической передачи данных учета. Ну или чтоб просто не лазить за фальшпанели для снятия показаний.

Некоторый опыт решения подобных задач есть, но всегда были или обе стороны системы передачи или прибор передавал информацию периодически без запроса, что позволяло ее перехватить и проанализировать. В данном случае я пока даже не смог заставить прибор хотя бы просто однократно включить передачу. Где-то проскакивала информация, что счетчики имеют адреса типа ХХ-ХХХХХ. Но это не совсем про такой счетчик, поэтому не точно. Думаю, что еще должна бы быть команда для опроса всех счетчиков, чтбы заставить их передать свои адреса...
Итак, какие варианты заставить счетчик что-нибудь передавать?

Есть приемник и передатчик и софт, который позволяет обмениваться с разными брелками (авто, ворота, шлагбаумы) и пультами (свет и т.д.)

Ну а если кто-то вдруг владеет полным описанием протокола - прошу поделиться.

**Дополнение 29.12.2019**

Первая часть вопроса была написана сумбурно, до глубокого изучения вопроса и, в основном, в надежде, что кто-нибудь владеет полной и достоверной информацией, в частности протоколом.
Надежды не оправдались, продолжаем изучать.

После ознакомления с описаниями стандартного оборудования для считывания информации со счетчиков по радиоканалу, сделаны следующие выводы:

- используются модемы 433МГц , чаще всего с модуляцией FSK, значит мои приемник и передатчик, которые умеют только OOK (модуляция включением/выключением) использовать не получится.
  Новые модемы заказал, буду ждать и изучать вопрос дальше.
- Большинство приборов учета вообще, и приборы, которые могут быть опрошены  такими же модемами, как и мой счетчик, используют протокол ModBus RTU.
  Значит высока вероятность что и у данного счетчика ModBus. И думаю что сам протокол очень похож на приведенные примеры протоколов ниже, кроме, возможно, конкретных адресов регистров.
  https://forum.lers.ru/download/file.php?id=17497
  https://forum.lers.ru/download/file.php?id=15252
  https://forum.lers.ru/download/file.php?id=19268

Как видите, все ссылки с форума ЛЭРС-учет, это оказался самый богатый ресурс по данному вопросу. Более того, других подобных ресурсов я вообще не нашел. Плохо искал?

Comment: Скорее всего РМД расшифровывается как Радиочастотная МоДуляция. Если нет способа иницировать передачу пакета - ответ "почти никак". Если только вы не поставите счётчик в режиме реальной работы, и не поставите логирование всего того, что происходит в эфире с заданными мощностями сигналов за энный промежуток времени.

Comment: Возьмите счетчик другой фирмы, которая открывает свой протокол. Или хотя бы предоставляет API в виде DLL для общения со своим счетчиком.

Comment: pepsicoca1, Вы видели описание счетчика? Посоветуйте какой другой с такими функциями взять. И чтоб наверняка был доступ к API или протоколу. Я не нашел...

Comment: Михаил Алексеевич, в реальной работе он стоит уже четвертый день, но это никак не влияет на его молчание... За вариант расшифровки спасибо, такого не находил. Но понимания это, к сожалению, никакого не добавляет...